# White-Space Preservation, Line Break Ignoring

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a text editor, and I wish to set an option of white-space CSS property so that spaces and nbsp's are preserved, but line breaks present in the HTML code do not cause a wrap.

The text editor that I am creating has margins on all sides, and I would like to have the text wrap once it hits the end of a <p> tag. I would like to have the user be able to place as many spaces in the document without them being compressed.

Currently, I have **white-space:pre-wrap;** , but any line breaks in the code for the document also cause line breaks in the document. These line breaks are caused by a document converter that I have, and I would not like to modify it, unless it is absolutely necessary. Though I am not absolutely sure, I highly doubt that Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, and Safari all avoid placing line breaks in the code. Therefore, I see that my best option may be to set the white-space property.

From what I have read about white-space:pre-line, it sounds like the EXACT opposite of what I would like, where it collapses spaces, and breaks on code line breaks;

I would like to have an answer that uses pure CSS, but I may be able to work with a little Javascript, but I would not like to, since this issue is not of the most EXTREME.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Here is a JSFiddle demonstration of what currently happens: http://jsfiddle.net/tXSQj/


**Code:**
    `<p>A    test 
        paragraph</p>`
**End of Code**


I would like to make it so that the word 'paragraph' in the example does not skip a line
do to the newline before it.

Comment: Why don't you post a self-contained demo showing what you have so far?

Comment: The only way I can see you being able to do that is with `&nbsp;`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I'm not sure if there's an easy CSS solution to this. It might just be easier to use JavaScript:

```
HTML:
<p id = "code">[stuff]</p>
<!-- Set the CSS white-space property to pre-wrap. -->

JavaScript:
var codeElem = document.getElementById("code");
codeElem.innerHTML = codeElem.innerHTML.split("\n").join(" ↵ ");
```

Comment: So in this piece of code, the code element gets split into an array by the newline, (newline getting stripped in the process), and then joined with the  ↵ character as one long line?

Comment: Well, since you've set the CSS `width` property, no. You would need to get rid of that for it to be all one element. If you want it to be one line, I'd suggest getting rid of the `width` property, setting the `height` property to `20px` and setting the `white-space` property to `nowrap`. No JavaScript needed. However, that wouldn't preserve white space. What this does is preserve whitespace and wrap the text when it touches the boundary of the document. It also makes the text always surrounded in blue while the solution I present in this comment doesn't.